# Is there a limit to the size of a query that can be executed by a sqlalchemy session?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm running a query in which I'm generating a table variable with inserts.  That means that I can make the query very large with a large number of inserts.  When I execute this query via a sqlalchemy session, it runs as intended so long as the number of inserts, or as I suspect the length of the query, is small enough.  When it is too large, nothing happens.  Does this make sense?  Is there a configurable query limit that I can set?  Or do I have to split my query up into pieces?

Thanks,
PiR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have probably hit the maximum length of allowed packet for your dbms. In case you were using MySQL in the backend, I suggest that you set the `max_allowed_packet` to a higher value like 512000000 for example. Or research a similar solution in case you use another dbms.

For MySQL I use:

```py
engine.execute('SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=512000000;')
```

to set this value globally until the server reboots. You can add it to your `my.ini`/`my.cnf` if you have enough permissions to do so.

I am not aware of a method to do this in a dbms-agnostic manner from SQLAlchemy.